# java чтение объектов из файла. очередь с приоритетом

Tags: java, очередь

Я считываю из текстового файла объекты. И всё бы ничего, но они не образуют очередь с приоритетом. Почему так происходит?(Пробовал создавать объекты для записи в файл - и там всё работало хорошо)
Подскажите, как это исправить?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;


class Order {
    int Id;
    String name;
    String courier;
    String dateTime;
    int type;

    public Order(int Id, String name,String courier,String dateTime,int type ) {
        this.setId(Id);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCourier(courier);
        this.setDateTime(dateTime);
        this.setType(type);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
        }
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCourier() {
    return courier;
    }
    public void setCourier(String courier) {
        this.courier = courier;
    }
    
    public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    public int getType() {
    return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String toString() {
        
        return "ID: "+ Id + " " +"Name of item: "+ name +" " + "Courier: "+ courier + " " +"dateTime: "+ dateTime + " "+"Type: "+ type + " "+"\n";
    }

}
  
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Stock.txt"));
                input.useDelimiter("-|\n");

                Order[] products = new Order[0];
                while(input.hasNext()) {
                    int Id = input.nextInt();
                    String name = input.next();
                    String courier = input.next();
                    String dateTime = input.next();
                    int type = input.nextInt();

                    Order newProduct = new Order(Id, name,courier,dateTime,type );
                    products = addOrder(products, newProduct);
                }

                /*for (Order product : products) {
                    System.out.println(product);
                }*/
                
                PriorityQueue<Order> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<Order>(5, new OrderComparator());
                pq1.add(products[0]);
                pq1.add(products[1]);
                pq1.add(products[2]);
                pq1.add(products[3]);
                pq1.add(products[4]);
                
                System.out.println("ORDERS:\n");
                for(Order pq2: pq1)
                    System.out.println(pq2);
        } 
    private static Order[] addOrder(Order[] products, Order productToAdd) {
        Order[] newProducts = new Order[products.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(products, 0, newProducts, 0, products.length);
        newProducts[newProducts.length - 1] = productToAdd;

        return newProducts;
    }
    
    }


class OrderComparator implements Comparator<Order>{

            public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
                if (o1.type > o2.type)
                    return 1;
                else if (o1.type < o2.type)
                    return -1;
                return 0;
                }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()

> The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

> Итератор возвращает элементы в произвольном порядке.

```
System.out.println("ORDERS:\n");
while (pq1.size() > 0)
  System.out.println(pq1.poll());
```

Comment: Но я ведь как-то выводил таким образом, когда записывал в файл и всё было в порядке.

Comment: если не так, то каким образом их можно "отсортировать"?

Comment: @idk_how "ведь как-то выводил таким образом, когда записывал в файл и всё было в порядке" - я понятия не имею, что это значит.

Comment: Когда я создавал объекты руками, а не читал из файла, и добавлял их в очередь, то через for они вывелись в желаемом порядке. Но здесь это почему то не сработало.

Comment: @idk_how Вам повезло. Как создаются объекты не имеет значения.

Comment: Удивительно, интересно. Но буду знать, спасибо.